# Show row values as columns to display in a gridview

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have a Mysql database with a table having two columns Department and deals as:

```
Department | deals 
HR         | A1  
Sales      | A2 
Revenue    | A1 
HR         | A3
```

I want to display the data in asp.net gridview as:

```
         A1| A2 | A3 
HR       1    0    1
Sales    0    1    0
Revenue  1    0    0
```

How can I do the same as the values under deals are not known or fixed.
I am using below but its not showing desired output

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(deals,char(10)))
FROM Table1
group by Department
```

Comment: You need [*pivoting model*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7675121/767881).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Department, 
       SUM(deals='A1') AS A1, 
       SUM(deals='A2') AS A2, 
       SUM(deals='A3') AS A3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Department
```

For `Dynamic Deals`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("SUM(deals='", deals, "') AS '", deals, "'")) INTO @temp
FROM Table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Department, ', @temp, 'FROM Table1 GROUP BY Department');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT Department, 
       SUM(IF(deals='A1', 1, 0)) AS A1, 
       SUM(IF(deals='A2', 1, 0)) AS A2, 
       SUM(IF(deals='A3', 1, 0)) AS A3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Department;
```

For `Dynamic Deals`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("SUM(IF(deals='", deals, "', 1, 0)) AS '", deals, "'")) INTO @temp
FROM Table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Department, ', @temp, 'FROM Table1 GROUP BY Department');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: if value of deals is also dynamic or not know then how can we do this?

Comment: @user2486976 Check my updated answer for dynamic deals